# How do I obtain a matplotlib renderer to pass?

Tags: python, matplotlib, renderer

I would like to call the `draw()` function of a matplotlib Spine instance.  The [documentation for Spines](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/spines_api.html#matplotlib.spines.Spine.draw) shows that `draw()` needs a 'renderer' parameter:

```
draw(self, renderer)
```

Code documentation for Renderers is nonexistent, as far as I can tell. All references to them as a class, like `matplotlib.backend_bases.Renderer` on the [Artist page](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html), don't provide links.  Searching turns up nothing but a table of renderers on the [Usage FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) page.  This tells me the names of the common renderers, but nothing about how to obtain a reference to one.  I've searched for a `get_renderer()` function in the docs, but it's turned up nothing so far.

How do I obtain a reference to a renderer in order to use the `spines.draw()` function?

Comment: Depending on the backend and any potential previous draw there may be a renderer available through `fig.canvas.renderer`, but it's unsafe to rely on it being present. The `draw()` function of individual artists is not actually meant to be called by the user in general, so maybe you want to get more into detail about why you think you need the renderer.

Comment: You're right, `fig.canvas.renderer` is not available to me.  "Not meant to be called by the user" is probably the best answer to this question, then, I guess.  Why I'm trying to call `draw()` is best posted as a separate question, so I'll do that.  Thanks!